# How I can typecast a collection of Child objects to a collection of Parent Object

Tags: java, collections, casting

I have one base class

```
public class BaseInfo { }
```

Then I have two child class from BaseInfo:

```
public class FunctionInfo extends BaseInfo {}
public class ComponentInfo extends BaseInfo {}
```

Now In rest layer there is one method using which I can get the collection of those child objects similar to below

```
Map<String, List<ComponentInfo>> allCompInfo  = componentLayer.findById(Id, true);  
Map<String, List<FunctionInfo>> allFunctionInfo = functionLayer.findById(Id);
```

Here In my next method I have to send the allCompInfo and allFunctionInfo both to get next info. Or I have to call twice that method If I am not sending them both together. In both cases the operation complexity is same. Iterating over two collection list.

I am curious to know is there any way to collect both child object collections into the BaseInfo collection. something like

```java
     Map<String, List<BaseInfo>> allInfo  = componentLayer.findById(Id, true);
     allInfo = functionLayer.findById(Id);
```

Basic upper casting I tried but the collection looks like work different way. Is there any way I can type cast a whole child collection to parent collection. It will be great help if one could help.

Comment: Just to be clear, you want to *merge* the two maps `allCompInfo` and `allFunctionInfo`? That is, add the key value pairs of the two maps into a single map, and where the keys collide, make a new list that contains the `BaseInfo`s of both values?

Comment: Yes. You are correct. I am trying to create a single collection called as 'BaseInfo' pulling the details from both componentLayer and FunctionLayer.

Answer (score 1):

`List<Component>` and `List<Function>` are just ***not*** subtypes of `List<BaseInfo>`. If they were a subtypes, everything you can do to `List<BaseInfo>` can also be done to `List<Component>`, right? But this is not the case - you can add a `Function` to a `List<BaseInfo>`, but you cannot add a `Function` to a `List<Component>`. Read more about this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2745265/is-listdog-a-subclass-of-listanimal-why-are-java-generics-not-implicitly-po).

`List<Component>` and `List<Function>` *are* subtypes of `List<? extends BaseInfo>` though. `List<? extends BaseInfo>` is very similar to `List<BaseInfo>`, but you cannot add elements to it (except null). You can combine the two maps into a `Map<String, List<? extends BaseInfo>>` like this:

```
var map = new HashMap<String, List<? extends BaseInfo>>(allFunctionInfo);
for (var entry : allCompInfo.entrySet()) {
    map.merge(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue(), (x, y) -> {
        // when keys collide, create a new List<BaseInfo> with elements from both lists
        var list = new ArrayList<BaseInfo>(x);
        list.addAll(y);
        return list;
    });
}
```

Alternatively, you can create copies of every `List<Function>` and every `List<Component>`. And the copies can be of type `List<BaseInfo>` instead:

```
var map = new HashMap<String, List<BaseInfo>>();
for (var entry : allCompInfo.entrySet()) {
    // new ArrayList<>(anotherList) creates a copy
    map.put(entry.getKey(), new ArrayList<>(entry.getValue()));
}
for (var entry : allFunctionInfo.entrySet()) {
    map.merge(entry.getKey(), new ArrayList<>(entry.getValue()), (x, y) -> {
        x.addAll(y);
        return x;
    });
}
```

You can extract this to a generic method that works on any base type and two subtypes:

```
private static <TBase, TSub1 extends TBase, TSub2 extends TBase> 
Map<String, List<TBase>> merge(Map<String, List<TSub1>> map1, Map<String, List<TSub2>> map2) {
    var map = new HashMap<String, List<TBase>>();
    for (var entry : map1.entrySet()) {
        map.put(entry.getKey(), new ArrayList<>(entry.getValue()));
    }
    for (var entry : map2.entrySet()) {
        map.merge(entry.getKey(), new ArrayList<>(entry.getValue()), (x, y) -> {
            x.addAll(y);
            return x;
        });
    }
    return map;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I shall check try this . lets see

Comment: Great answer. It should be shown to all students who study Java generics I think.

Answer (score 0):

If there are no "key" collisions (https://www.baeldung.com/java-hashmap-advanced#collisions-in-the-hashmap) then you can try this approach:

```
Map<String, List<? extends BaseInfo>> allInfos = new HashMap<>();
allInfos.putAll(compoments);
allInfos.putAll(functions);
```

Comment: This for this small snippet. This looks promising. But I have to check that key collision case once.

Comment: I see the answer from @Sweeper has already solution for collisions.

Answer (score 0):

You must create a new `List<BaseInfo>` and copy the child class objects over.

So this answer is broadly useful, here I've used more familiar classes from the JDK instead of your custom classes: Parent class `Number` with child classes `Integer` and `Long`.

Given:

```
Map<String, List<Integer>> allCompInfo  = new HashMap<>();
Map<String, List<Long>> allFunctionInfo = new HashMap<>();
```

and you want to populate a `Map<String, List<Number>> allInfo` with them:

Either copy all values into the base map imperatively, manually handling merges:

```
Map<String, List<Number>> allInfo = new HashMap<>();
allCompInfo.forEach((k, v) -> v.forEach(e -> allInfo.merge(k, new ArrayList<>(List.of(e)), (a,b) -> { a.addAll(b); return a;})));
allFunctionInfo.forEach((k, v) -> v.forEach(e -> allInfo.merge(k, new ArrayList<>(List.of(e)), (a,b) -> { a.addAll(b); return a;})));
```

Or, do it in one line via a stream, which would scale better if you add more child classes (and it looks cooler):

```
Map<String, List<Number>> baseInfo = Stream.of(allCompInfo, allFunctionInfo)
   .map(Map::entrySet)
   .flatMap(Set::stream)
   .flatMap(e -> e.getValue().stream().map(v -> new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<String, Number>(e.getKey(), v)))
   .collect(groupingBy(Map.Entry::getKey, mapping(Map.Entry::getValue, toList())));
```

Comment: Instead of a complicated and expensive `allInfo.merge(k, new ArrayList<>(List.of(e)), (a,b) -> { a.addAll(b); return a;})` you can use `allInfo.computeIfAbsent(k, key -> new ArrayList<>()).add(e)`

Comment: And the Stream operation can be simplified to `Stream.of(allCompInfo, allFunctionInfo) .flatMap(m -> m.entrySet().stream()) .collect(groupingBy(Map.Entry::getKey, flatMapping(e -> e.getValue().stream(), toList())))`